# How to validate a user an redirect him to different page in flask

Tags: html, flask

I am pretty new to flask.
I have an upcoming project and i am using a template to create my login page beautifully.
I am supposed to read username as admin and password as admin and redirect him to a new page but i am not able to figure out the problem.The page is not changing even after i submit the form also.

HTML:

```
<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="get" id="form1">
                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-26">
                    Welcome
                </span>
                  <span class="login100-form-title p-b-48">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-font"></i>
                </span>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" >
                    <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" value="{{ request.form.username }}">
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="username" > </span>
                </div>

                <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" >
                    <span class="btn-show-pass">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                    </span>
                    <input class="input100" type="password" name="password" value="{{ request.form.password }}" >
                    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="password"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                    <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                        <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" form="form1" value="submit">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request,session,flash
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)
@app.route('/adminhome')
def adminhome():
    return "HEllo ADmin"
@app.route('/dealerhome')
def dealerhome():
    return 'hello dealer'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] == 'admin' and request.form['password'] == 'admin':
            return redirect(url_for('adminhome'))
        if request.form['username'] == 'dealer@gmail.com' and request.form['password'] == 'dealer':
            return redirect(url_for('dealerhome'))
        else:
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    return render_template('admin.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is the code for app.py and the first code is for html template
when i type username and password and press login this shows up on terminal
`"GET /?username=admin&password=admin HTTP/1.1" 200 -`
I dont understand what it is
I think the form is not getting submitted.

Comment: Your form has no action and method attribute. The browser will then issue a GET with request args for your fields, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: i didnt understand. can you be more elaborate.thank you

Comment: he means you need to make some changes in your template. Change your opening form tag to the following: <form action="{{ url_for('login')}}" method="POST" class="login100-form validate-form" id="form1"> and see if that makes a difference.